# How to create flag inform whether was some change in two columns on ID in PROC SQL in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sql, time, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

```
ID  | val1| val2
----|-----|-----
123 | M   | M
123 | M   | P
123 | P   | P
444 | PR  | PR
444 | PR  | PR
567 | PR  | M
567 | M   | M
99  | PR  | P
```

And I need to creeate new column "col1" with values 0/1:

- If some ID never changed the value PR from column "val1" to the value of M or P in column "val2" then this ID has 1 else 0

So, as a result I need something like below:

```
ID  | val1| val2| col1
----|-----|-----|----
123 | M   | M   | 1
123 | M   | P   | 1
123 | P   | P   | 1
444 | PR  | PR  | 1
444 | PR  | PR  | 1
567 | PR  | M   | 0
567 | M   | M   | 0
99  | PR  | P   | 0
```

Because:

- 123 - has 1 in "col1" because has never changed PR to M or P
- 444  - has 1 in "col1" because has never changed PR to M or P
- 567 - has 0 because changed PR to M
- 99 - has 0 because changed PR to P

How can I do that in PROC SQL in SAS Enterprise Guide ?

Comment: Is ID a character field and is your data sorted alphabetically on ID?

Comment: ID is numerical field and my data are not sorted alphabetically on ID :)

Comment: Should the order be prevailed?

Comment: Note that the tool used to generate and submit the code (Enterprise Guide) should not matter.  Unless you are asking for some menu option in the Enterprise Guide interface that could generate the right SAS code for you.

Comment: do not have to be in the same order ;)

Comment: It is a good practice to right align numeric data, so it stands out as not beeing alphabetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a single value at the ID level that is replicated onto all observations for that level of ID?  PROC SQL makes that easy because it will automatically remerge aggregate values back to the detailed observations.

It sounds like the test you want is

```
val1='PR' and val2 in ('M' 'P')
```

You then want the overall result to be 1 (TRUE) when that expression is never true.

```
data have ;
  input ID val1 $ val2 $ EXPECT ;
cards;
123  M    M    1
123  M    P    1
123  P    P    1
444  PR   PR   1
444  PR   PR   1
567  PR   M    0
567  M    M    0
99   PR   P    0
;

proc sql;
  create table want as 
    select *
         , min(not (val1='PR' and val2 in ('M' 'P'))) as COL1
    from have
    group by id
  ;
quit;
```

Result:

```
Obs     ID    val1    val2    EXPECT    COL1

 1      99     PR      P         0        0
 2     123     P       P         1        1
 3     123     M       M         1        1
 4     123     M       P         1        1
 5     444     PR      PR        1        1
 6     444     PR      PR        1        1
 7     567     M       M         0        0
 8     567     PR      M         0        0
```

Comment: Perfect if the dataset is not huge and the order does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Solution if the can be changed:

```
proc sort data=have;
    by ID;
run;
data want;
    * for every ID, read the data you have twice *;
    set have (in=first_pass) have (in=last_pass);
    by ID;
    
    * From the first pass, remember if any observation "changed" from PR to P or M *;
    retain col1;
    if first.ID then col1 = 0;
    if val1 eq 'PR' and val2 in ('P', 'M') then col1 = 1;
    
    * only output the results from the second pass *;
    if last_pass;
run;
```

Comment: If the order does matter, you can solve it with a hash table.

Comment: is this solution create new table in WORK library ? if yes what is their name (this new, created table) ?

Comment: Yes, it creates `WORK.WANT`, unless you change it to `data have;`